# Laravel querying eager load

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got this query in Laravel:

```
return Forum::with(['users' => function($query){
            $query->select('user.id', 'user.name', 'user.last_name');
        }])->latest()->withCount('messages')->paginate(10);
```

This returns all users that have posted a message in a forum.

On my **forum** model I've these relations:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'message');
}


public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}
```

I would like to receive only the latest user that has posted a message. How could I do this?

Comment: I guess forum has a relationship with messages, right?

Comment: Could you post your table structure?

Comment: Yes, a forum ```hasMany messages``` I've changed my question.

Comment: can you pos the latest function

Comment: That's a function from ```Laravel```.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the last user by messages relationship, try this:

```
return Forum::with(['messages' => function($query){
    $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
},'messages.users'])->first();
```

Comment: That returns this: ```SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'messages.created_at' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `user` where `user`.`id` in (1, 2) order by `messages`.`created_at` desc)```

Answer (score 0):

Use `has()` method and order by created_at in descending order.

```
User::has('forums.messages')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
```

Comment: @Jamie use `with('forums')->has('forums.messages')` then.